# Crond permissions

Tags: centos, permissions, cron, dmidecode

I have a problem regarding permissions in a CentOS server.

I created a NetCore application that reads some values from dmidecode. When I deployed the application in my CentOS server, I runned the following command:

```
chmod 777 ApplicationName
```

Then, I execute it, and eveything works fine.

My problem is when I try to set that application in crond, for that I do:

```
1) service crond stop

2) crontab -e

3) * * * * * cd /ApplicationFolder && ./ApplicationName

4) service crond start
```

My application is executed, but I can't get the dmidecode values I am trying to read, I am assuming that I am having a permission problem, because it works fine when executing as a console application.

I tried to set a user in the crond line by doing:

```
 * * * * * root cd /ApplicationFolder && ./ApplicationName
```

But nothing happens, the application isn't even started...

Does anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

As proposed by the comments, I changed the crontab to:

```
 * * * * * /ApplicationFolder/ApplicationName
```

But the same is happening...

The reason why I think I am having a problem related with permissions its because if I run the program as an application values are logged into a text file, while when I execute the application using crond the same info is logged but the values are empty.

I also read that when reading Serial Numbers from dmidecode we would need root privileges, but my current account using crontab is already the root account.

Comment: Don't do `cd` but use absolute path to the program. In that case `/ApplicationFolder/ApplicationName`. Does your application writes those values to file or to stdout?

Comment: There's absolutely no need to stop and restart the cron daemon when adding a cron job.

Comment: Are you sure that your user have write permission in directory in which you want to create your file? Edit your post as you trying new solutions. What is the location of file that should be created by your app?

Comment: Ok, changed the line to * * * * * /ApplicationFolder/ApplicationName The values are logged to a text file. After the change I still can't get the values. The reason why I think its related with permissions its because if I execute the application with console everything works fine.

Comment: I edited my post with some conclusions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone havin problem like this I managed to solve my problem by using absolute paths.

It seems that cron has some problems with relative paths...

Basically instead of having:

```
 dmidecode
```

I have:

```
 /usr/sbin/dmidecode
```

That did the trick for me.

Comment: Glad you got to the bottom of it! Another option would be to put `PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin` at the top of the crontab.